# tensorboard debugger is not working

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorboard, debuggervisualizer

I have tried to initialise the tensorboard debugger via the following command

```
   tensorboard --logdir summarytrain/ --debugger_port 7000
```

The output from this command is:
        Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                        File "c:\users\krisb\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\plugins\debugger\debugger_plugin_loader.py", line 79, in _ConstructDebuggerPluginWithGrpcPort                                                           from tensorboard.plugins.debugger import debugger_plugin as debugger_plugin_lib                                       File "c:\users\krisb\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\plugins\debugger\debugger_plugin.py", line 36, in                                                                                               from tensorboard.plugins.debugger import debugger_server_lib                                                          File "c:\users\krisb\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\plugins\debugger\debugger_server_lib.py", line 33, in                                                                                           from tensorflow.python.debug.lib import grpc_debug_server                                                             File "c:\users\krisb\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\debug\lib\grpc_debug_server.py", line 27, in                                                                                              import grpc                                                                                                         ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'grpc'                                                                                                                                                                                                     During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:                                                                                                                                                                             Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                        File "c:\users\krisb\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main               "**main**", mod_spec)                                                                                                 File "c:\users\krisb\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code                          exec(code, run_globals)                                                                                               File "C:\Users\krisb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\tensorboard.exe__main__.py", line 9, in    File "c:\users\krisb\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\main.py", line 36, in run_main                                                                                                                          tf.app.run(main)                                                                                                      File "c:\users\krisb\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 124, in run                                                                                                                _sys.exit(main(argv))                                                                                                 File "c:\users\krisb\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\main.py", line 45, in main      default.get_assets_zip_provider())                                                                                    File "c:\users\krisb\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\program.py", line 165, in main                                                                                                                          tb = create_tb_app(plugins, assets_zip_provider)                                                                      File "c:\users\krisb\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\program.py", line 199, in create_tb_app                                                                                                                 window_title=FLAGS.window_title)                                                                                      File "c:\users\krisb\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\backend\application.py", line 126, in standard_tensorboard_wsgi                                                                                         plugin_instances = [constructor(context) for constructor in plugins]                                                  File "c:\users\krisb\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\backend\application.py", line 126, in                                                                                                         plugin_instances = [constructor(context) for constructor in plugins]                                                  File "c:\users\krisb\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\plugins\debugger\debugger_plugin_loader.py", line 87, in _ConstructDebuggerPluginWithGrpcPort                                                           err.message +                                                                                                       AttributeError: 'ModuleNotFoundError' object has no attribute 'message'

I have tried to install GPRC via pip install gprc but i get the following error too
           Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in 
            C:\Users\krisb\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h7zjk7ly\grpc\

Totally stuck - anyone have any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the solution to this problem is to install

```
         grpcio
```

Therefore enter

```
      pip install grpcio
```